# Write C/C++/Python code on an Android cellphone

Tags: android, python, c, platform

I have this cellphone which runs Android OS 2.6. Due to some reasons, I want to write code directly on my cellphone just as what we do in front of our PC.

So,

1. Can we make the Android cellphone a develop-platform? I mean write/compile/run C code on Android cellphones?
2. If we can, how?

Comment: It's gonna be pretty hard to type on the phone if you ask me.... I mean imagine all the buttons you gotta press to use emacs on it :P

Comment: yeah, I know that, actually I use `vim`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, [for C/C++](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en) (but sorry, not free). I don't use python, don't know if it have similar one or not. Anyway, this is just-for-fun compiler, I don't think it can compile real code with such low processing power and memory.

If you didn't like this app or don't have money, try to compile [tiny C](http://bellard.org/tcc/) for android.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually there will be plenty of Android applications for programming on Android phones, but for now, the easiest route may be to [install Ubuntu](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/) on your Android phone.

Comment: After the installation, I can just use the phone as a Ubuntu PC? Shell/Python scripting will be available ?

Comment: Depends on if you can root your phone *I* *guess*, but, yes, you can then do pretty much anything.

Comment: I sure can root my phone. So after I install the Ubuntu, then I can use the phone just like a PC, right? :)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Of course, there are no guarantees, but many have done it before you.

Answer (score 1):

I installed sl4a which eventually gave me a sandboxed perl/python/tcl/lua enviroment. I then found their binaries in the shell and relocated them to my path so I could call them from cli. I also purchased c4droid and found that it had the tiny c binary in the shell.